# clearTimeout() is affecting something completely separate in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, timeout, jsx

Upon clicking the submit button many things happen including cancelling the countdown clock. I am using `setTimeout()` and it actually works just fine, but for some reason I can no longer delete items. When I remove the `setTimeout()` deleting the items works just fine. I really have no idea what's going on as they are completely separate things and use completely separate variables.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { Image } from './Image.js'
import { Button } from './Button.js'
import { images } from './assets/images.js'
import { Countdown } from './Countdown.js'
import { DisplayCount } from './DisplayCount.js'
import { Inputs } from './Inputs.js'

class Game extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.timer = null
    this.thoughts = []
    this.thought = []

    this.state = {
      currentImg: 0,
      timer: null,
      ranNum: null,
      thought: [],
      isSubmitted: false
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handleDeleteClick = this.handleDeleteClick.bind(this).  < -------------
  }

countdownClock = async (newRanNum) => {
const startingNum = newRanNum * 20;
for(let i = startingNum; i >= 0; i--) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
         this.setState({
           timer: i
         })
        resolve()
     }, 1000)
   });
  }
}

handleChange(event, index) {
  const inputs = [...this.state.thought];
  inputs[index] = event.target.value
  this.setState({
    thought: inputs
  });
}

  handleClick(){
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
    let newRanNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    this.countdownClock(newRanNum)
    this.generateStateInputs(newRanNum)
    // this.generateInputs(this.state.thought)
    let current = this.state.currentImg;
    let next = ++current % images.length;
    this.setState({
      currentImg: next,
      ranNum: newRanNum
    })
  }

  generateStateInputs(newRanNum){
    let inputArray = []
    for(let i = 0; i < newRanNum; i++){
      inputArray.push('')
    }
    return this.setState({
      thought: inputArray
    });
  }

   handleSubmit(event) {
     if(event){
    clearTimeout(this.timer)    <------------------------------------------
    event.preventDefault();
    let thought = this.state.thought.map(word => word + ' ');
    console.log(thought)
    this.thoughts.push(thought)
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      thought: []
    })
     }
  }

  handleDeleteClick(index){ <-------------------------------------------------------
    return this.thoughts = this.thoughts.filter(thought => thought !== this.thoughts[index])
  }

  render(){
    let src = this.state.currentImg;
    return(
      <div>
        <Countdown name={'Countdown: '} countdown={this.state.timer} />
        <DisplayCount name='Word Count: ' count={this.state.ranNum} />
        <Image src={images[src]} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} name='Generate Inputs' />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <ol>
            {this.state.thought.map((input, index) => (
              <Inputs type='text' key={index} value={input} onChange={event => { this.handleChange(event, index) }} className='textInputs' />
            ))}
        </ol>
       <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
        </form>


        <div>
            <ol>
              {this.thoughts.map((thought, index )=> 
                 <DisplayPoem key={index} onClick={() => { this.handleDeleteClick(index) }} name='Delete Thoughts' value={thought} /> <---------------------------------------------
              )}
            </ol>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class DisplayPoem extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <li>
        <span>{this.props.value}</span>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.name}</button>
      </li>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You are updating state every second for your entire app when you are calling setState in your timer. This is going to cause a lot of issues with stale state,wrong state and reset of values when you think they are there. You don't have keys on your components so it is going to rerender them aswell.That is why it is working when you remove the timing. I would start by moving your countdown class to its own component and then see what happens. Here is a quick example of a timer in its own component that you can communicate with: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-blackburn-ho43x?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Still new to React, ive never seen ```useState``` before. gonna look it up and dig into the code you sent. thank you so much for your response.

Comment: no problem, message me if you need any help.

Comment: I think I figured out the code and read about hooks. I want the timer to start on a button click. I read that ```useState()``` only sets the initial value, which will be `null` and I cant quite figure out how to use ```setCoundown``` when I try to input my random number as this ```setCountdown(ranNum)``` it crashes the app. Not sure where to proceed.

Comment: Updated to a click with random number https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-blackburn-ho43x?file=/src/TimerClick.js